# How to run a function and load Viewbag on every page load?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, methods, global

Here is my issue.  On my _Layout, I have a help button that shows up on every page in my MVC application.  Is there a way to assign the Viewbag with my simple model without having to put in every ActionResult method throughout my application?  A global method?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var query = db.OnlineHelp.Where(a => a.PageUrl == Request.RawUrl).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.htmlraw = query.PageContent
}
```

and on my _Layout.chtml

```
@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.htmlraw)
```

The Request.RawUrl tracks the user and depending on the page, the database is queried and returns the result such as /Home/Index

Comment: Take a look at ActionFilters, they allow you to inject your code into the request lifecycle.  From within here, you should be able to set ViewBag properties as you see fit.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: What about a BaseController class? Do you have access to Request.RawUrl in a controller constructor?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an implementation issue.

Comment: I used the BaseController, thanks @Graham.